# What's the difference between 'fallacy' and 'misnomer'?

Tags: differences, connotation

In which contexts the usage vary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though they both imply there is some kind of mistake, they are pretty different kinds of mistakes.

- a fallacy is an error in inference. You have some facts and do some reasoning but come to a faulty (or unsubstantiated) conclusion. Then you've committed a 'fallacy'. Coming to a wrong conclusion is a fallacy.
- a misnomer is simply a wrong name for something, in the sense that the given accepted name is at odds with the nature of the things itself. A 6'7" basketball player named 'Shorty' has a misnomer (the name 'Shorty' is a misnomer).

Answer (score 4):

A *fallacy* is a common misconception. A [logical fallacy](http://www.logicalfallacies.info/) is one type of example.

*Misnomer* refers, more specifically, to a wrong name or inappropriate designation -- for instance, calling Native Americans "Indians."

An easy way to remember the difference is to remember that *misnomer* is derived from the the Latin word for "name," *nominare*.

Comment: ...Or calling them Native Americans. :) Some would point out that thee folks were here before the European explorers got around to renting boats. The term I've heard recently that I liked was "First Nations".

Answer (score 1):

I think Wikipedia has one of the better succinct definitions: [**"...a fallacy is incorrect reasoning in argumentation resulting in a misconception."**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy)  It should be noted that there are a number of distinct logical fallacies, and that an entire section of philosophy is devoted to them.  The referenced link is a good start for exploring the various flavors of fallacies.

@Mitch's answer to a misnomer is well stated.

Answer (score 1):

A *fallacy* has a technical and a common usage, but both could be loosely summarized as "an error in reasoning" or a "logical fault".

Poor reasoning can also be called *fallacious* reasoning.

"Begging the question" is an example of a fallacy.
From [nobelief's fallacy list](http://www.nobeliefs.com/fallacies.htm):

> begging the question (or assuming the answer): (e.g., We must encourage our youth to worship God to instill moral behavior.) But does religion and worship actually produce moral behavior?

Here's an example usage from a comment on [Serendipity: Or, What has Software Engineering got to do with Climate Change?](http://www.easterbrook.ca/steve/?p=1322)

> I only bother to bring it up because, IMHO, an appreciation of this fallacy is necessary to appreciate the real differences between technical software validation and its verification.

Something being a 'fallacy' tends to indicate an error of process.

A *misnomer* is simply misnaming something, or calling something by the wrong name or a misleading name.

This can be minute and technical or broad and ideological or philosophical:

> Calling that little hill Mount Brawn is an egregious misnomer.
>
> Calling that a budget *plan* is a misnomer -- there's no plan, it's just budget fraud.

It is incorrect to use *misnomer* to mean an incorrect assumption, poor reasoning, or more general kind of error where another word should be used instead:

*Don't use it this way, please:*

> It's a misnomer that all dogs bark.

Ugh. From the another comment found in the [wilds of the Internet](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/kate-korman/tick-tock-my-egg-freezing_b_834302.html%29%5D):

*Again, please, no:*

> There's still a misnomer that single women pushing thirty are fatally flawed or intimidating[...]